# Check if a point is inside the geometry in PostGIS from PHP

Tags: php, coordinates, polygon, postgis, geometry

I have geometry type defined and and both polygons and circles were enteried into this.Polygon was enteried using query of following type:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON$polygon')
```

where $polygon contains the points.

And I have entered the circle in the same column as:

```
ST_Buffer((ST_GeomFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)')), $radius)
```

Now I need to check if a given point lies inside  and of the geometry.

Can anybody help me?

I have tried using this query:

```
ST_CONTAINS(shape,ST_GeomFromText('POINT($longitude $latitude)'))
```

where shape is my column name of type Geometry. But this gives me always true for the circles even if they are outside the circle.

Comment: An example circle and point would be helpful.

Comment: do you mean a circle in POSTGIS?

Comment: I entered (0,0) for circle with lon,lat and rad=(85,27,5000)

Comment: Yes, if you could put a WKT sample of your circle and a point that you think should be outside of the circle, then we can test.

Comment: I think I have the SRID system wrong for the circle input query and also the unit of radius.Can you tell me the correct query

Comment: You want to use SRID 4326 if you use using lat/lon. Still can't help without some actual geometries, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments, you are using geometry types with a spatial reference system that uses units in degrees (SRID=4326). Making a circle that has a radius of 5000 degrees is a massive circle that will contain everything on earth.

You may either want to use a projected spatial reference system with units of meters, or you may want to consider using the geography type. You can also buffer a circle using the geography type, then transform it back to a geometry type.

Comment: Can you suggest the SQL for using geography type and then transform it

Comment: `ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(85, 27)::geography, 5000)::geometry`

Comment: I did that but when I tried to find the centroid of circle it gives different than what I have given.Why is that?

Comment: Because ST_Centroid is assuming a flat-Earth geometry; there currently isn't any centroid function for geography types. The distance of the centroid to the original point is 0.2367 m.